# Marker style of legend and the graph are not matching?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Below is the code I am using for generating the plot, but the issue is style of the marker in the graph is different from that of the plot

```
sns.set_style(rc={'boxplot.flierprops.markeredgecolor':'black' ,'boxplot.flierprops.markeredgewidth':1.25,'boxplot.flierprops.markerfacecolor':'white'})
fig, scatter = plt.subplots(figsize = (6,4), dpi = 100)
scatter = sns.lineplot(data=df_whole,x='shortest_distance',y='similarity',style ='Metric',hue='Metric'
                       ,markers=True,lw=1,markeredgewidth=1.25,markeredgecolor='black',markersize=7,dashes= False,errorbar=None,markerfacecolor='white')
scatter.set(title='TF-IDF')
scatter.legend(title = "Similarity Methods",prop={'size': 12})
```

[image: graph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seaborn uses complex combinations of matplotlib elements to create its plots, and tries to make the legend as compact as possible, the legend is often custom-made.  As such, seaborn unfortunately does not always take into account all matplotlib-level parameters.

In this case, the problem can be worked around via assigning these parameters again to the legend handles. Here is an example using one of seaborn's test datasets:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

flights = sns.load_dataset('flights')
markerprops = dict(markeredgewidth=1.25, markeredgecolor='black', markersize=7, markerfacecolor='none')
ax = sns.lineplot(data=flights, x='year', y='passengers', style='month', hue='month',
                  markers=True, lw=1, dashes=False, errorbar=None, **markerprops)
ax.set(title='TF-IDF')
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
for h in handles:
    h.set(**markerprops)
ax.legend(handles=handles, title="Months", prop={'size': 12}, ncol=3)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.lineplot with updated markers in the legend]

PS: Matplotlib functions usually return the graphical elements they created (e.g. scatter dots or lines), while seaborn (and pandas) usually returns the subplot (`ax`) or grid of subplots. As such, giving the name `scatter` to the return value of `sns.lineplot` might be confusing when comparing code with other matplotlib and seaborn examples.